# initialize only once non static local variable

Tags: c++, recursion, local-variables, static-variables

```
void foo() {    
    static int x{0};
    int y{0}; // this one
    // dosomething like ++y
    foo();    
}
```

Is it possible to have variable 'y' initialized only once(when foo called first time, not in each call) but separate independent local copy of it in each stack frame. while possible to change it in each stack frame(like ++y).

Comment: Please show how your desired results should be different from that of a static variable.

Comment: Pass it as an argument to `foo()`.

Comment: I agree with @Evg. You can set the default value for y as 0 and wouldn't have to pass a value for your first call.

Comment: While there is only one `x`, there is one independent `y` in every call to `foo`. You must initialize all of them or none of them.

Comment: Together with recursion, this is a red flag to me. Perhaps just use function arguments?

Comment: No idea what you're trying to get. Can explain the exact behavior you want to see?

Answer (score 1):

> initialize only once non static local variable

By calling the function only once.

If you want a local variable initialised once in a function called multiple times, then that's what static local variables are for.

P.S. Your example function has infinite recursion. It will overflow the stack.